# Apex upgrade from 4.0.1 to version 4.1

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am new to upgrading Apex versions. We will be upgrading from v: 4.0.1 to v: 4.1. I have read the documentation, just wanted to know do I have to export the data prior to the upgrade or will the data be migrated with the upgrade?

Thank you for all your help so far,
Melanie

Comment: Where you say "Data" do you mean the Apex applications you have developed?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to perform an export\import Your Apex applications will be migrated with the upgrade.

The 
[documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21673/overview.htm#CEGEFBFI) doesn't explain it well but it states:

> If you have version 1.5.x, 1.6.x, 2.0.x, 2.2.x, 3.0.x, 3.1.x, 3.2.x or
>   4.0x of Oracle Application Express, following any of the installation
>   scenarios in this guide upgrades your Oracle Application Express
>   instance to version 4.1 and creates Oracle Application Express 4.1
>   database objects in a new schema and migrates the application metadata
>   to the new version.

Comment: Thank you carpenteri, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest conservative approach and making export in any case. During our upgrade we hit specific problems with LDAP authentication. So in most cases you could stay with direct upgrade, but in case you use functionality outside of Oracle you will probably need the export for tunning external functionality (trial-error).